# AWS Lex Android SDK start voice interaction without InteractiveVoiceView

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I work with `AWS Lex Android SDK 2.4.2`

Is there any way to start voice interaction with Lex bot **WITHOUT** pushing `InteractiveVoiceView` component? For example after pushing custom button, changing fragment of other action.

Comment: Have you looked at the Lex sample here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/LexSample?  You don't have the use the InteractiveVoiceView.  I just provides the button view that shows feedback activity while the conversation is happening.

If you look here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/LexSample/app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/sample/lex/MainActivity.java you can see that the onClick just calls another class in the example InteractiveVoiceActivity.class that handles the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
voiceView = (InteractiveVoiceView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.voiceInterface_weight);
voiceView.performClick(); // simulating clicking on the InteractiveVoiceView
```